# Cannot find require index of (string) , Object, Date, Json after upgrading to typescript 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

After converting to typescript 2.0 from 1.8 im getting alot of errors.
The errors and typescript code is.

**Cannot Find "JSON"**

```
set = JSON.parse(settin);
```

**Property 'indexOf' , concat does not exist on type 'string'**

```
var appSetting : string = this.en.APP_SETTINGS;
        var appSummary : string = this.en.APP_SUMMARY;
        while (appSetting.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            appSetting = appSetting.replace("/", "\\");
        }
```

**Cannot find name 'Object'**

```
public async GetSettings(): Promise<Object> {
```

**Cannot find array in Array()**

```
let items: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
```

**Cannot find Date**

```
public lastUpload: Date = null;
```

There were problems like require and Promise also but solved after adding shim and types

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.32",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "vscode": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "github": "^2.6.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "node-watch": "0.4.0",
    "open": "^0.0.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "temp": "^0.8.3"
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

`{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "noLib": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}`

Comment: It sounds like there is no reference to `lib.d.ts`. How did you upgrade? Are the error messages after running `tsc`?

Comment: i just replaced the version of TS in package.json to 2.0.3 and removed the node_modules folder and run the npm install again. `tsc` is setup already in tsconfig.json i have posted that json in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line:

> "noLib": true

In your  in `tsconfig.json`, which [causes the compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to

> not include the default library file (lib.d.ts)

I haven't actually ever used that, but from what you're describing it seems that if you'll remove this line the errors should get away.